# Cannot find submodule in a package on one PC but not on another PC

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have the simplest possible test package that works perfectly on one PC, but not on another, both running Python 3.7.3 64bit Windows.

The problem is that the main script cannot import submodule that sits in a subfolder using relative path, only on one of the machines.

The package structure

```
pypkg/
    __init__.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        app.py
    util/
        __init__.py
        util.py
```

src/app.py works like this

```
# app.py

from pprint import pprint
import sys
pprint(sys.path, indent=4)

from util import util


def main():
    print('this is app.')
    util.func()
    pprint(sys.path, indent=4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

util/util.py looks like this

```
def func():
    print('this is func from util.')
```

Now on the first PC where I wrote the code, I open my command prompt, `cd /path/to/pypkg`, then run

```
python src\app.py
```

This gives me:

```
G:\pypkg>python src\app.py
[   'G:\\pypkg\\src',
    'C:\\Apps\\Csound6_x64\\bin',
    'G:\\pypkg',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
this is app.
this is func from util.
[   'G:\\pypkg\\src',
    'C:\\Apps\\Csound6_x64\\bin',
    'G:\\pypkg',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Notice that the current working directory, i.e., the root of this package is automatically added to `sys.path`.

Now copying the same package to another PC under the **same** logical location, and run the code still under `/path/to/pypkg/`.

This gives me:

```
g:\pypkg>python src\app.py
[   'g:\\pypkg\\src',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from util import util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

Notice that this time the working directory is not added to `sys.path` by itself.

Other than the fact that the second machine's command prompt shows all drive letters in lowercase while the first all capital, I can't figure out where the difference between the machines is.
Please help!

**UPDATE**

I now found a workaround to make things behave the same: Run the script like this:

```
python -m src.app
```

Why??

**UPDATE 2**

As @meowgoesthedog questions if I added the current working directory to PYTHONPATH, by hand, I did another test: I go to yet another level up to `G:\`, added `__init__.py` to `G:\`, then turn app.py into:

```
# app.py

from pprint import pprint
import sys
pprint(sys.path, indent=4)

from pypkg.util import util


def main():
    print('this is app.')
    util.func()
    pprint(sys.path, indent=4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It still runs on my PC, which gives:

```
G:\>python g:\pypkg\src\app.py
[   'g:\\pypkg\\src',
    'C:\\Apps\\Csound6_x64\\bin',
    'G:\\',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
this is app.
this is func from util.
[   'g:\\pypkg\\src',
    'C:\\Apps\\Csound6_x64\\bin',
    'G:\\',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37',
    'C:\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
```

You can see that cwd is once again added to PYTHONPATH.

**UPDATE 3**

I tested the same code on a Mac and the result matches the other "not-working" PC, i.e., the cwd is **NOT** automatically added to PYTHONPATH. Tested with both py27 and py37.

So it's likely that something is different on my main PC where it adds cwd to PYTHONPATH automatically. But how?

Comment: Lowercased drive letter may be an issue. How are you open command prompt for that?
see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9448 or https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16648

Comment: @Sav on both machines, I do Win+R then `cmd` to bring up the command prompt.

Comment: Python [does *not* automatically add the current directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to `sys.path`. Are you sure you didn't manually add `pypkg` to `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I'm absolutely sure I did not add that path by hand.